# Return one line per contact in searchkit

Tags: searchkit

I'n building a report of contact demographics using searchkit for event participants

Starting with the Contact entity, joining participant and event entities and initially filtering by event type and then event end date.

All working fine and as expected, and for contacts that have attended more than one event in a quarter it is returning multiple rows for each contact.

[image: Screenshot of report results showing 3 rows for one contact]

What is the simplest way to set the search to return one row per contact? (I'd be able to do this in drupal views, so that's there as a fall back.)

Comment: Group By!!!!!!!

Darn it, so busy staring at field transformations I overlooked the blindingly obvious.

Comment: add that as an Answer Craig

Comment: Cheers Pete, will do after the weekend. Currently not logged into the work system to grab a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After selecting the entities to search the Group By option~~

[image]

Allows you to choose any of the included entities to group results by

Contact ID- to return one line per contact
Activity ID- to return one line per activity- etc